# connect/token endpoint gave me 400 bad request (invalid_client)

Tags: c#, reactjs, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect

I have a reactjs application, I'm using `react-oidc-context` library, it's a wrapper of `oidc-client-js`. I have a problem where I'm getting `Bad Request (400)` on `connect/token` after successful login and have no idea what I did wrong. I tried this on Postman and getting the same result

Here's my oidc config

```
const oidcConfig = {
  authority: "https://<site>/identity",
  client_id: "test-portal",
  redirect_uri: "https://localhost:3000",
  response_type: "code",
  scope: "openid"
}
```

Here's the error

[image]

Here's my IdentityServer4 setup

```
Allowed Scopes  
email, openid, profile

Redirect URIs
https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback  
https://localhost:3000  
  
Flow: AuthorizationCodeWithProofKey  
AccessTokenType: JWT  

Allowed CORS Origins:  
https://localhost:3000  
https://oauth.pstmn.io
```

Comment: What is in the response body and in the idp logs?

Comment: @JanGaraj: `{"error":"invalid_client"}` is the response, unfortunately I don't have access to the IDP log

Comment: I can see that different configuration in your oidc-client config and postman, my hunch is `client_secret` is missing from oidc config and from postman you are passing clientsecret but you are using `Basic` Authorization which should be `OAuth 2.0`. If you select `OAuth 2.0` as your Authorization method and click on send button on Postman it will redirect you to the default browser's web page and will prompt you with IdS4 login page and on successful login it will redirect back to the postman with the access token.